# CakePHP 3 how to limit number on items in contain per item not globally

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have articles connected with categories. I would like to get at most two articles for each category. There is many to one connection. So I use the following.

```
$query = $categories->find()->contain([
    'Articles' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
            return $q->limit(2); 
        }
    ]
]);
```

Unfortunately the limit 2 seams to be global. I get 2 articles from the first category an then no articles connected with other categories.

How can I set the limit per item and not globally.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [custom finder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods).

```
$query = $articles->find()->contain([
    'Authors' => [
            'finder' => 'limitedAuthors'
        }
    ]
]);
```

I haven't used this myself yet, so not sure if it goes into the Articles or Authors table. Guess it goes in the AuthorsTable.

```
public function findLimtedAuthors(Query $query, $options) {
    return $query->limit(2);
}
```

Comment: It does not work in 3.1. I edited a little bit my question - now it can be clearer

Comment: Unfortunately the limit is still (like in my example) global.